# Configuring spring WebSocketMessageBroker with RabbitMQ and distributed microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-websocket

I'm trying to use RabbitMq with spring `WebSocketMessageBroker`, across distributed microservices.

The setup I'm working with is

[image]

Within the WebSocketMessageBroker, I'm using the following config, taken from the docs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
      registry.addEndpoint("/push").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
   }

   @Override
   public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
      registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/", "/app");
      registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
      registry.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher("."));
   }
}
```

Given this config, what exchange / queue should `MyMicroservice` publish to in order for the message to be proxied through to the Stomp service?

I've tried the following (on the publishing side -- within MyMicroservice)

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRabbit
public class Config {
    public static final String WEB_QUEUE = "/topic/myNotificationTopic";
    public static final String WEB_EXCHANGE = "web.exchange";

    @Bean
    Queue webQueue() {
        return new Queue(WEB_QUEUE, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange webExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(WEB_EXCHANGE);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue webQueue, TopicExchange webExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(webQueue).to(webExchange).with(WEB_QUEUE);
    }

}

@Component
public class ExamplePublisher {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    public void sendMessage() {
        amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(Config.WEB_QUEUE, "Hello, world");
    }
}
```

However, the message doesn't appear to be proxied over the WebSocket connection.

To be clear, my questions are:

- Is this type of distributed configuration supported out-of-the-box?
- Given the example config, what is the relationship between RabbitMq topics that the services can publish to, and the Stomp messagebroker proxying?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear by your explanation why you are going to use Spring AMQP for the STOMP interaction, although it is possible anyway.

I'd suggest to take a look to the `StompClient` support in the [Spring Messaging](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-client), if you are going to send STOMP messages to the target destination directly from Java.

With the Spring AMQP (or just AMQP protocol) you should follow some RabbitMQ STOMP Adapter [rules](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html):

> Topic Destinations
>
> For simple topic destinations which deliver a copy of each message to all active subscribers, destinations of the form `/topic/<name>` can be used. Topic destinations support all the routing patterns of AMQP topic exchanges.
>
> Messages sent to a topic destination that has no active subscribers are simply discarded.
>
> AMQP 0-9-1 Semantics
>
> For `SEND` frames, the message is sent to the `amq.topic` exchange with the routing key `<name>`.
>
> For `SUBSCRIBE` frames, an autodeleted, non-durable queue is created and bound to the `amq.topic` exchange with routing key `<name>`. A subscription is created against the queue.

Pay attention that you should have `subscription` first anyway, otherwise your messages will be lost without subscribers.